# I am unable to change the URL Structure in My PHP Website

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I have created website and i want to change its URL Structure.
For example.

```
http://www.haitibravo.com/market/detail.php?add_id=73
```

I want to show it without ? Mark like

```
http://www.haitibravo.com/market/product/73
```

how i can show URLs like this. Please help me. I have tried many techniques but i am fail.

Comment: Google `Apache Mod Rewrite examples` OR `Mod Rewrite SEO Friendly URLs`

Comment: I am sorry I am unable to understand what you said. Can you please give me some examples

Answer (score 1):

Make a .htaccess file and save the following code in it.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?r=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/item/$ index.php?r=$1
```

Comment: Should i add these lines into .htaccess file?

Comment: Yes. And one more thing if you running it on localserver. Then search on google how to run .htaccess on software you are using for localhost.

Comment: No No I m running it on my Website

Comment: And In my Domain there are 4 directories. Should i add the file in each directory. Directory means. Market, magazine, searches, each directory has a different website but domain name is same..

Comment: You can save it in root folder and write rules for sub-directories too in root folder's file. Like if you have sub-directory dmain.com/sub-directory you can write rules in root file as

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) sub-directory/$ index.php?r=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)sub-directory/item/$ index.php?r=$1

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ detail.php?add_id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/product/$ detail.php?add_id=$1

I written these codes and Saved file haitibravo.com/market
But not worked. It still showing the Older thing 
http://www.haitibravo.com/market/detail.php?add_id=73

Comment: With Sub-directory Still not working.. Now codes are these..
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)market/$ detail.php?add_id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)market/product/$ detail.php?add_id=$1

Comment: Read The Question now. I am sure now you can understand better

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On 
/* this enables you to write urls in desired fashion */
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ detail.php?add_id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/product/$ detail.php?add_id=$1

/*Something like this should redirecto from detail.php?add_id=n to your desired url */
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:detail\.php)?\?add_id=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ item/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

/* You may need to play with the above slightly... */
```